# How to fix footers dropping below page

Tags: latex

For the first 2 pages the page number is at the right place, then for pages 3 and 4 it drops to a place that won't show up when converted to pdf.

```
% Footers
\lfoot{} % Define left footer
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\cfoot{}% Define center footer
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your `\footheight` or `\headheight` is too small. `fancyhdr` will inform you about this in the .log file and also give you the minimum value that you need. Then you can increase it to a suitable value, e.g. with

```
\setlength{\headheight}{10pt}
```